# Ionic3 / Ionic2+ settings.json file for environment variable configuration

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Many frameworks offer configuration files to put informations such API URL or API password (settings.py with Django, settings.json with Meteor).

I don't find anything in the official doc or in stackoverflow about this.

Do you know a way to set variables configuration properly in an Ionic2+ project ?